# Visual Basic Components

Tags: vba

My visual Basic will not allow me to access the components this was not a problem till recently

```
lblCharactorName.txt = "Karle"
```

will appear with Red Error squiggles under the lblCharactorName
please help

the (name) property is labeled right, it just won't let me access my labels and Textboxes

Comment: the Lable is named lblCharactorName

Comment: Check again. Character is normally spelled with an 'e'.

Comment: If it's a Label, then you want `lblCharactorName.Caption`

Comment: For one, add a semi colon at the end. Two, are the labels in the same form and where are you accessing them from? Also, are you sure you changed the name in the properties of the label? Plus i would personally fix the spelling from Charactor to Character.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA Label controls don't have .txt or .text, you should use instead **.Caption = "my text"**

[image: Check image :)]